# Replace color in pixi js

Tags: webgl, pixi.js, webgl2

Help me understand how to change colors in PIXI
There is a picture of red color
Suppose
[image: http://data.3dtuning.com/tun/4nI0lcnL9b.jpg]
It is necessary to change the color from red to green, for prtimerna.
But so that the shadows remain, that is, given the tone.

I can do it pixel by pixel.
If there are ideas on the algorithm, I will also be very grateful

```
var cR = baseData[i];
                var cG = baseData[i + 1];
                var cB = baseData[i + 2];

                if (alpha) {
                    currentData[i + 3] = alpha[i / COMPONETNS_PER_PIXEL];
                } else {
                    currentData[i + 3] = baseData[i + 3];
                }

                if (cR === cG && cR === cB) {
                    currentData[i] = currentData[i + 1] = currentData[i + 2] = cR * brightness;
                    continue;
                }

                var gray = Math.min(cR, cG, cB);

                // parts should be red
                var percent = (cR - gray) / 255;

                currentData[i] = (cR + (color.r - 255) * percent) * brightness;
                currentData[i + 1] = (cG + color.g * percent) * brightness;
                currentData[i + 2] = (cB + color.b * percent * 0.9) * brightness;
```

But I would like to change this to VVGL
I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I have a hint but sadly not a full answer. I checked out all the pixi examples once and tried to understand [the one with a color filter](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/filters/filter.js) .

In the example the colormatrix filter is applied to the "app.stage.filters" and it is replacing colors.

It uses the following code:

```js
var filter = new PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter();
app.stage.filters = [filter];


app.ticker.add(function(delta) {
  count += 0.1;

  var matrix = filter.matrix;

  matrix[1] = Math.sin(count) * 3;
  matrix[2] = Math.cos(count);
  matrix[3] = Math.cos(count) * 1.5;
  matrix[4] = Math.sin(count / 3) * 2;
  matrix[5] = Math.sin(count / 2);
  matrix[6] = Math.sin(count / 4);
}
```

The [Pixi Documentation has the following description](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter.html#matrix) to the matrix parameter which sadly does not help understanding it:

> The matrix of the color matrix filter.
>   Default Value:
>   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

I also found [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8qRE.jpg) in [this Post about Flash](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/manipulate-visual-effects-with-the-colormatrixfilter-and-convolutionfilter--active-3221) that i assume describes the parameters of the matrix and the conversion.

I tried to use these recources for creating my own filter but i failed and did not have time to try further.